# Strange behavior with css pseudo selector :checked

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, checked

I'm using a pure CSS solution to display a rating of five stars on my website. This technique is described in https://www.danielkeithjones.com/Articles/Web_Development/Pure_CSS_5_Star_Rating_System_with_Radios/ and I use it in various sections of my website, but inexplicably works in some cases but not in others. Due to inherited properties?
The technique makes use of pseudo selector ":checked" and general-sibling combinator selector ( ~ ).

**HTML Markup:**

```
<div class="rating">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" disabled="disabled" checked/>
    <span id="hide"></span>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" disabled="disabled"/>
    <span></span>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" disabled="disabled"/>
    <span></span>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" disabled="disabled"/>
    <span></span>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" disabled="disabled"/>
    <span></span>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" disabled="disabled"/>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

**CSS Rules:**

```
.rating input[type="radio"] {
    position:absolute;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    -moz-opacity:0;
    -khtml-opacity:0;
    opacity:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:17px;
}

.rating span {
    width:24px;
    height:15px;
    line-height:15px;
    padding:1px 22px 1px 0; /* 1px FireFox fix */
    background:url(stars.png) no-repeat 3px -19px;
}

/* Change span immediately following the checked radio */
.rating input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
    background-position:3px -19px;
}


/* Reset all remaining stars back to default background.
   This supersedes the above due to its ordering. */
.rating input[type="radio"]:checked + span ~ span {
    background-position:3px 1px;
}
```

As I said above, I use this technique in different pages of my website and when it fails, the problem is that the last two CSS rules do not apply. I have verified that by removing the pseudo selector ":checked" these rules are correctly applied.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look here http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953

Comment: Thanks @Lyall! I've looked it but I have not found anything useful for my problem. Could you be a little more precise?

Comment: I suspect you'll have to make a demo of it **not** working for us to debug...

Comment: Ok @Paulie_D, I'll try to recreate the problem in jsFiddle or similar

Comment: Hello, I managed to reproduce the error. It seems that the error occurs when using the OWL Carousel component. http://jsfiddle.net/u4r3xdmk/6/.

Comment: Hi again @Paulie_D, finally I have reproduced the error. You can take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4r3xdmk/6/). It seems that the error is caused by the OWL Carousel component but I can not avoid it. Thanks.

Comment: @Patxi I don't understand your problem. In your JSFiddle demo, `background-position: 3px -19px` is applied to the `span` directly after the checked `input` element, and `background-position: 3px 1px` is applied to all `span` elements thereafter. Is this a browser-specific problem?

Comment: I don't think so @James Donnelly. I've tested in Chrome, Safari and Firefox with identical results. In the JSFiddle, I created a OWL carousel with three identical items(cloned). In all of them, the "checked", is the third star (ie, a score of 3 out of 5) but only in the third item works properly. In the first two items all stars appear activated (5 out of 5) and without the style ".rating input[type="radio"]:checked + span ~ span" applied. In your testing, Can you see the three items with a score of 3 out of 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Problem

Your problem is that all your radio buttons have the same `name` attribute. This means that they all belong to the same group of input controls. The way radio buttons work is that only one in a group can be checked at any one time. Whilst the `checked` attribute may be specified on the first two, the *checkedness state* on these is `false` because the latter one takes priority.

Take this example:

```html
<input type="radio" name="foo" checked />
<input type="radio" name="foo" checked />
<input type="radio" name="foo" checked />
<input type="radio" name="bar" checked />
```

Even though all three of the `"foo"` radio buttons have the `checked` attribute specified, only the third one is actually checked because they all share the same `name` attribute. The `"bar"` radio button, which has a different `name`, is also checked because it does not belong to the `"foo"` group.

### The Fix

The fix, therefore, is to ensure your different groups of radio buttons have different `name` attributes. In your case, all three groups share the `name`: `"gl_satisfaction_12"`. In this [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u4r3xdmk/8/) I've renamed the three groups to `"group_1"`, `"group_2"` and `"group_3"`.

Comment: Thank you @James Donnelly, You're right, your fix solves the problem.
But unfortunately, it is a problem of the reproduction that I did in jsFiddle. I cloned the same item three times to meet the requirements of the OWL Carousel and I did not realize that I introduced the error that you comment. Interestingly with the same results. 
However, on my website each group of radio buttons has a different name and the problem is still reproduced. Sorry for my mistake.
I will continue trying to reproduce the problem in jsFiddle, but with the fix that you propose.
Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

removing the `disabled` attributes from radio buttons makes it work fine. How can you make a radio button `:checked` if it's disabled.

Comment: I tried to remove the attribute "disabled" but the problem persists. The attribute "disabled" is used because this component is reused, both to show the score (read-only) as for enable the user to rate (input)